# Testing file existence using NSURL

Tags: cocoa, osx-snow-leopard, nsurl, core-foundation, nsfilemanager

Snow Leopard introduced many new methods to use NSURL objects to refer to files, not pathnames or Core Services' FSRefs.

However, there's one task I can't find a URL-based method for: Testing whether a file exists. I'm looking for a URL-based version of [-[NSFileManager `fileExistsAtPath:`]](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/fileExistsAtPath:). Like that method, it should return `YES` if the URL describes anything, whether it's a regular file, a directory, or anything else.

I could attempt to look up various [resource values](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURL/resourceValuesForKeys:error:), but none of them are explicitly guaranteed to not exist if the file doesn't, and some of them (e.g., [NSURLEffectiveIconKey](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSURLEffectiveIconKey)) could be costly if it does.

I could just use NSFileManager's `fileExistsAtPath:`, but if there's a more modern method, I'd prefer to use that.

Is there a simple method or function in Cocoa, CF, or Core Services that's guaranteed/documented to tell me whether a given file (or file-reference) URL refers to a file-system object that exists?

Answer (score 144, accepted):

NSURL does have this method:

```
- (BOOL)checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError:(NSError **)error
```

Which "Returns whether the resource pointed to by a file URL can be reached."

```
NSURL *theURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/Users/elisevanlooij/nonexistingfile.php" 
               isDirectory:NO];
NSError *err;
if ([theURL checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError:&err] == NO)
    [[NSAlert alertWithError:err] runModal];
```

Comment: To any iPhone OS devs thrown off by this answer: `checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError:` is only available in 10.6 and later and not yet available in the iPhone SDK.

Comment: Update: It is available as of iOS 4.

Comment: The iOS docs in XCode 3.2.5 (which supports iOS 4.2) state: "This method is unimplemented in iOS, so it performs no operation."

Comment: Another update ... it performed no operation in iOS4, although apparently it is now supported on the iPhone as of iOS5.0

Comment: Note that this only works for local files and will always return NO for remote URLs

Comment: Good lord who named this function?

Answer (score 30):

On iOS I couldn't find any other way...

```
NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"file.type"];
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[storeURL path]]) {...}
```

Answer (score 10):

Here is the **Swift 2** answer:

```
var error:NSError?
let folderExists = theURL.checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError(&error)
```

Comment: It should be `checkResourceIsReachable()->Void` and throw exception, however, what you said is correct for Xcode 7.x

Comment: *throw error. Swift errors are different from Objective-C exceptions. Similar syntax, but different purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Determining if a given file (or file-reference) URL refers to a file-system object that exists is inherently costly for remote resources, the 10.6 only (no iPhoneOS) api's for this CFURLResourceIsReachable() and [NSURL checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError:] are both synchronous, even if you would be using them, for a lot of files you would still be looking at a significant delay overhead.

What you should do is implement your own asynchronous checking routine with caching that separately creates a list of valid resources.

Otherwise the notes for CFURLResourceIsReachable in the header state :

> An example would be periodic maintenance of UI state that depends
>   on the existence of a particular document.  When performing an
>   operation such as opening a file, it is more efficient to simply try the
>   operation and handle failures than to check first for reachability.

Comment: I doubt it's slow... NSURL maintains a link to the HFS+ filesystem entry that it represents. According to Apple, URLs are *much* faster than paths for all filesystem operations.

Answer (score 1):

Because NSURL can represents more that local file-systems, I don't think that there is a  generic method that can test for their existence in a reliable way. At least, the Cocoa foundation does not contains such a function (as far as I know).

If you only deal with local file-systems, I suggest you to create a category for `NSURL` or for `NSFileManager`, with a `urlExists:` message. It would convert the `NSURL` to a `NSString` (normalized path) and then invoke the `[NSFileManager fileExistsAtPath:]` message.

Comment: You can couple the aforementioned `checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError:` with `isFileURL` to keep it sane.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift you can use the `checkResourceIsReachable()` method, which unfortunately will either return `true` (if the file is reachable) or throw an error (explaining why it cannot be reached).

To get a bool true/false value instead, use this syntax:

```
let exists = (try? inputFile.checkResourceIsReachable()) ?? false
```

If you'd like to log the error:

```
let exists: Bool
do {
  exists = try inputFile.checkResourceIsReachable()
} catch {
  exists = false
  print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Keep in mind this is an expensive operation and it could be out of date immediately after (if some other process is deleting a or unmounts a disk file while you're checking if it exists).

In general the preferred approach is not to check wether a file exists, instead simply attempt to read or write to a file and handle any error afterwards if it fails.