# Checking if file exists when file on an external device

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsfilemanager

A playlist file .m3u contains entries available on an external device (a USB key in this case) such as:

```
/Volumes/KINGSTON/folder/mytitle.mp3
```

I'd like to check if the file exists:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"/Volumes/KINGSTON/folder/mytitle.mp3"];
NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSLog(@"%d",[manager fileExistsAtPath:[url absoluteString]]); //returns 0. I expect 1
```

I also tried:

```
NSURL *u = [[NSURL alloc]initWithScheme:@"/Volumes" host:@"/KINGSTON" path:@"/folder/mytitle.mp3"];
NSLog(@"%d",[manager fileExistsAtPath:[u absoluteString]]); //0
```

What did I do wrong?

Thanks,

Roland

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"/Volumes/KINGSTON/folder/mytitle.mp3"];
> ```

That string does not describe a URL. It's a pathname. Use `fileURLWithPath:`.

> ```
> NSLog(@"%d",[manager fileExistsAtPath:[url absoluteString]]);
> ```

`absoluteString` does not return a path; it returns a string describing a URL. Use `path`.

Or, better yet, [use `checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError:`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1929185/30461).

> I also tried:
>
> ```
> NSURL *u = [[NSURL alloc]initWithScheme:@"/Volumes" host:@"/KINGSTON" path:@"/folder/mytitle.mp3"];
> ```

/Volumes isn't a scheme, /KINGSTON isn't a host, and /folder/mytitle.mp3 is a path but does not refer to anything that exists.

The scheme for a file URL is `file:`, and the host is generally either localhost or the empty string. The path of a file URL is the complete absolute path to the file.

Answer (score 1):

In your first example, you need to use `+[NSURL fileURLWithPath:]`. In your second example, I see what you're trying to do, but you're simply going about it the wrong way.

I assume there's a reason you're bothering with `NSURL` when you have the path you could pass directly to `-fileExistsAtPath:`?

Comment: NSURL is what Apple recommend in its documentation. There is no other motivation